# LDAP users cannot login to Mediawiki

Tags: ldap, mediawiki

I have a private MediaWiki with the MediaWiki *LdapAuthentication* extension and the php *ldap* extension installed; and the following `LocalSettings.php` LDAP configuration:

```
    require_once( "$IP/extensions/LdapAuthentication/LdapAuthentication.php" );
    $wgAuth = new LdapAuthenticationPlugin();
    $wgLDAPDomainNames = array( "MYDOMAINALIAS" ); // alias name for the domain
    $wgLDAPServerNames = array( "MYDOMAINALIAS" => "192.168.1.82" ); // ldap server IP or DNS
    $wgLDAPSearchStrings = array( "MYDOMAINALIAS" => "uid=USER-NAME,cn=users,dc=mydomain,dc=com" );
    $wgLDAPUseLocal = true; // ldap authentication only or ldap plus local mediawiki authentication
    $wgLDAPBaseDNs = array("MYDOMAINALIAS" => "dc=mydomain,dc=com"); // dn base
    $wgLDAPEncryptionType = array( "MYDOMAINALIAS" => "clear" ); // type of encryption clear, tls or ssl
    $wgLDAPDebug = 3; // debuggin level
    $wgDebugLogGroups["ldap"] = "/volume1/web/MediaWiki/debug-wiki.log" ; // the file has to exist
```

when I try to log in the wiki with an LDAP user I get the following error:

> Incorrect username or password entered. Please try again.

The *debug-wiki.log* shows the following message:

> 2019-10-23 15:47:56 192.168.1.79 wiki-wiki_ikb_en_: 2.1.0 Entering Connect
>
> 2019-10-23 15:47:56 192.168.1.79 wiki-wiki_ikb_en_: 2.1.0 It looks like you are missing LDAP support; please ensure you have either compiled LDAP support in, or have enabled the module. If the authentication is working for you, the plugin isn't properly detecting the LDAP module, and you can safely ignore this message.

I know that the LDAP server is working because it is also serving a PGina user authentication service which is working correctly. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server had installed two versions of PHP, and the one running the webserver did not have the *ldap* extension active. Once it was installed, it worked as expected. I am leaving the question here in case it can be of any help to someone with a similar scenario.